# Why i cant cut range from array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
positions = ['GK', 'M', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'A', 'M', 'M', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'M', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'GK', 'D', 'D', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'GK', 'D', 'GK', 'D', 'D', 'M']
heights = [191, 184, 185, 180, 181, 187, 170, 179, 183, 186, 185, 170, 187, 183, 173, 188, 183, 180, 188, 175, 193, 180, 185, 170, 183, 173, 185, 185, 168, 190, 178, 185, 185, 193, 183]

np_positions = np.array(positions)
np_heights = np.array(heights)
gk_heights = np_heights[np_positions == 'GK']
a_heights = np_heights[np_positions == 'A']

a = gk_heights[gk_heights > 190]
print(gk_heights[a < 195])
```

I want to cut heights items which are in range from 190 to 195 and i get mistake. What's wrong and maybe you can advice me better method to do this?

Comment: `a` is of size 2, but `gk_heights` is of size 4. Hence, your mask `a < 195` is too short.

Comment: independently of your code, what exactly is your goal and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
a = gk_heights[(190 < gk_heights) & (gk_heights < 195)]
print(a)

# Output
array([191, 193])
```

Or with your method:

```
a = gk_heights[gk_heights > 190]
a = a[a < 195]
print(a)

# Output
array([191, 193])
```

Comment: What you want is not clear. Is it what you expect?

Comment: ok, thanks, i need to find sum of max height in this range. I dont understand how to implement 2 methods simultaneously

Comment: What is the result (value) you expect please?

Comment: one number i think

Comment: Like `max(gk_heights[(190 < gk_heights) & (gk_heights < 195)])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    a = [i for i in gk_heights if i > 190 and i < 195]
    
   print(a)#[191, 193]
   print(np.max(a)) #if you just need the maximum (193)
```